# HTML page randomly showing gigantic fonts

Tags: html, wordpress, fonts, font-size

I have a Wordpress website.

Upon visitng the pages for the first time I randomly sometimes get gigantic fontsizes as show in [this image](http://i1285.photobucket.com/albums/a586/leonardocito/BugsandQuirks/immagine0_zps0dc4a110.png). In such cases, pressing F5 and relading the page fixes the problem as show in [this second image](http://i1285.photobucket.com/albums/a586/leonardocito/BugsandQuirks/immagine1_zpsfebabb77.png).

Has anybody got any idea?

Please find below my css:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td
{
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;

    font-family: 'Cardo', "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}

html  /****/
{
    font-size: 62.5;
}

#comments
{
}
.comment-content p
{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
body
{
    line-height: 1;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    clear: both;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ol, ul
{
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote
{
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after
{
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
del
{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
/*tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup*/
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
table td, table th
{
    padding: 5px;
}
a img
{
    border: none;
}
a, a:visited {
    outline: 0;
}
/*=Fonts
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
body, input, textarea, .page-title span, .pingback a.url
{
    font-family: 'Cardo', "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;

}
h3#comments-title, h3#reply-title, #access .menu, #access div.menu ul, #cancel-comment-reply-link, .form-allowed-tags, #site-info, #site-title, #wp-calendar, .comment-meta, .comment-body tr th, .comment-body thead th, .entry-content label, .entry-content tr th, .entry-content thead th, .entry-meta, .entry-title, .entry-utility, #respond label, .navigation, .page-title, .pingback p, .reply, .widget-title, .wp-caption-text
{
    font-family: 'Cardo', "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;

}
input[type=submit]
{
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
}
pre
{
    font-family: "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace;
}
code
{
    font-family: Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
}
#site-title a
{
    font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
#colleft #access a
{
    font-family: Geneva, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.widget-title
{
    font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
.entry-title
{
    font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
.entry-content
{
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}
/*
=Typography
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.widget-area, #commentform
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
.entry-content
{
    display: inline-block;
    /*color: #BBB;*/
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    line-height: 26px;
    line-height: 1.6rem;

    /*font-family:'Cardo', "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;*/

    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.entry-content:after 
{
    content: ".";  
    display: block; 
    height: 0; 
    clear: both; 
    visibility: hidden; 
}
/* Hides from IE-mac */
* html .entry-content 
{height: 1%;}

.entry-content
{display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
body
{
    color: white;/*#CCC;*/
}
#site-title a
{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#colleft #access a
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.0rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height:1.2rem;

}
#colophon a, #colophon a:visited
{
    color: #CCC;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
#colophon
{
    font-family: 'Cardo', serif, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
.entry-title
{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-size: 2.3rem;

    color: #EEE;
}
.widget-title, #reply-title
{
    color: #777;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.form-allowed-tags
{
    font-size: 12px;
}
.page-title
{
    font-size: 19px;
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#credits, #credits a {
    font-size:12px;
    font-size:1.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#site-generator {

}
/*Global styles
----------------------------------------------------------------
Text elements*/
p
{
    margin-bottom: 1.625em;
}
ul, ol
{
    margin: 0 0 1.625em 2.5em;
}
ul
{
    list-style: square;
}
ol
{
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
ol ol
{
    list-style: upper-alpha;
}
ol ol ol
{
    list-style: lower-roman;
}
ol ol ol ol
{
    list-style: lower-alpha;
}
ul ul, ol ol, ul ol, ol ul
{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
dl
{
    margin: 0 1.625em;
}
dt
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
dd
{
    margin-bottom: 1.625em;
}
strong
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
cite, em, i
{
    font-style: italic;
}
blockquote
{
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 3em;
}
blockquote em, blockquote i, blockquote cite
{
    font-style: normal;
}
blockquote cite
{
    color: #666;
    font: 12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
pre
{
    color: #333;
    background: #BBB;
    font: 13px "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 1.625em;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0.75em 1.625em;
}
code, kbd
{
    font: 13px Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
}
abbr, acronym, dfn
{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
    cursor: help;
}
address
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 1.625em;
}
ins
{
    background: #FFF9C0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
sup, sub
{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-size: 1.0rem;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
sup
{
    bottom: 1ex;
}
sub
{
    top: 0.5ex;
}
/*Forms*/
input[type=text], input[type=password], textarea
{
    background: #EEE;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #bbb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #bbb);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #BBB;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    color: #888;
}
input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus
{
    color: #373737;
}
textarea
{
    padding-left: 3px;
    width: 98%;
}
input[type=text]
{
    padding: 3px;
}
input#s
{
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 28px;
}
input#searchsubmit
{
    display: none;
}
a, a:visited
{
    color: #FF6347;
}
/*=General Styles
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.entry-header
{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.entry-title
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;/*#222;*/
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#respond p
{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#respond input, #comments #respond textarea
{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#respond
{
    color: #444444;
}
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
#site-generator
{
    padding-left: 60px;
}
#main
{   
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 40px;
}
/*
#main:after
{ 
 content: ".";  
 display: block; 
 height: 0; 
 clear: both; 
 visibility: hidden; 
}*/


/* Hides from IE-mac */
* html #main 
{height: 1%;}

#main 
{display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */

#image-navigation
{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.page-title
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.entry-content h1, .entry-content h2, .entry-content h3, .entry-content h4, .entry-content h5, .entry-content h6
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.entry-content img
{
    outline: 2px solid white;   
}
.archive .entry-title
{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.attachment .entry-caption 
{
    margin-top:10px;
}
#comments-title
{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.comment-content
{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #AAA;
}
#comments
{
    clear: both;
}
#comments .navigation
{
    padding: 0 0 18px;
}
h3#comments-title, h3#reply-title
{
    color: #999;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
h3#comments-title
{
    padding: 24px 0;
}
.commentlist
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.commentlist li.comment
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 0 24px;
    padding: 0 0 0 65px;
    position: relative;
}
.commentlist li:last-child
{
    border-bottom: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#comments .comment-body ul, #comments .comment-body ol
{
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}
#comments .comment-body p:last-child
{
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
#comments .comment-body blockquote p:last-child
{
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.commentlist ol
{
    list-style: decimal;
}
.commentlist .avatar
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 0;
}
.comment-author
{
}
.comment-author cite
{
    color: #CCC;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.comment-author .says
{
    font-style: italic;
}
.comment-meta
{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 0 13px;
}
.comment-meta a:link, .comment-meta a:visited
{
    color: #888;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.comment-meta a:active, .comment-meta a:hover
{
    color: #FF4B33;
}
.commentlist .even
{
}
.commentlist .bypostauthor
{
}
.reply
{
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0 0 24px;
}
.reply a, a.comment-edit-link
{
    color: #888;
}
.reply a:hover, a.comment-edit-link:hover
{
    color: #FF4B33;
}
.commentlist .children
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.commentlist .children li
{
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.nopassword, .nocomments
{
    display: none;
}
#comments .pingback
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}
.commentlist li.comment + li.pingback
{
    margin-top: -6px;
}
#comments .pingback p
{
    color: #888;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 0;
}
#comments .pingback .url
{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.entry-meta a
{
    color: #EEE;
}
/*=Structure
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#commentform
{
    padding: 10px;
}
#wrapper
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;


}
#colleft
{

    width: 230px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;

    border-top: 0;

    background:rgba(70,70,70,0.90);
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(57,57,57,0.6);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#99464646',endColorstr='#99464646',GradientType=0);
}

#branding h1,#branding h2
{
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin:0;
    paading:0;
}

#logo
{
    margin-top:0;
    height:144px;
    background:url('images/Locandina_Logo.jpg')  no-repeat center;
    background-position:50% 0;
}

#wrapper #colleft a img {
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
}

.home #page
{
    display: none;
}
#page
{   
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    border: none;
    display: block;

    width: 730px;

    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    height:auto;

    background:rgba(70,70,70,0.90);

    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#99464646',endColorstr='#99464646',GradientType=0);

    overflow:hidden;
}
#primary
{
    /*float: left;*/
    width: 80%;
}
#page #main .full-width {
    width:100%;
}
#content
{
    margin-right:40px;
}

#main .widget-area
{
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0px;
}
.widget-area
{
    color: #999;
}
#colophon
{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    border-top: 1px solid #222;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.home #colophon
{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    border-top: 1px solid #222;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 15px;
    position: fixed;
}
#content .post
{   display: block;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.post .entry-title a, .post .entry-title a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #EEE;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.page-template-template-blog-php .page-title {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
/*Increase the size of the content area for templates without sidebars*/
.full-width #content, .image-attachment #content, .error404 #content
{
    margin: 0;
}
/*Text meant only for screen readers*/
.screen-reader-text, .assistive-text
{
    position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
/*IE6, IE7*/
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
/*Alignment*/
.alignleft
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.alignright
{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}
.aligncenter
{
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
/*=Header
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#site-title
{   text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
    padding:0 5px;
}
#site-description
{
    text-align: center;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding:0 5px;
}
/*=Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#access
{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 80%;
}
#access ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
#access li
{
    position: relative;
}
#access li a
{
    padding: 10px;
}
#access a
{
    display: block;
    line-height: 15px;
    padding: 0 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#access ul ul
{
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
#access ul ul ul
{
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#access ul ul a
{
    width: 10em;
    height: auto;
}
#access li:hover > a, #access ul ul :hover > a
{
    background: #DEDEDE;
    color: #555 !important;
}
#access ul ul a:hover
{
    color: #555 !important;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
    color: #555;
}
#access .menu li a:hover
{
    color: #555;
}
#access .children li
{
    background-color: #999999 !important;
}
#access .sub-menu li
{
    background-color: #999999 !important;
}
.menu
{
    text-align: center;
}
.menu li
{
    border-top: 1px solid grey;/* #222;*/
}
.menu .sub-menu li
{
    border-top: 1px solid #888;
}
.menu .children li
{
    border-top: 1px solid #888;
}
.menu li:first-child
{
    border: 0;
}
/*=Content
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.sticky
{
}
.entry-meta
{
    color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 10px;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.single-author .entry-meta .byline
{
    display: none;
}
#content nav
{
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
#content nav .nav-previous
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
#content nav .nav-next
{
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
}
#content #nav-above
{
    display: none;
}
.paged #content #nav-above, .single #content #nav-above
{
    display: block;
}
#nav-below
{
    margin: 1em 0 0;
}
.page-link
{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
}
.page .edit-link
{
    clear: both;
}
/*404 page*/
.error404 .widget
{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.error404 .widget .widgettitle, .error404 .widget ul
{
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.error404 .widget_tag_cloud
{
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
/*Notices*/
.post .notice, .error404 #searchform
{
    background: #EEE;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
}
/*Image Attachments*/
#image-navigation {
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.image-attachment div.entry-meta
{
    float: left;
}
.image-attachment nav
{
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
}
.image-attachment .entry-content
{
    clear: both;
}
.image-attachment .entry-content .entry-attachment
{
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
.image-attachment .entry-content .attachment
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
/*Aside Posts*/
.format-aside .entry-header
{
    display: none;
}
.single .format-aside .entry-header
{
    display: block;
}
.format-aside .entry-content, .format-aside .entry-summary
{
    padding-top: 1em;
}
.single .format-aside .entry-content, .single .format-aside .entry-summary
{
    padding-top: 0;
}
/*Gallery Posts*/
.format-gallery .gallery-thumb
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
/*Image Posts*/
.format-image .entry-header
{
    display: none;
}
.single .format-image .entry-header
{
    display: block;
}
.format-image .entry-content, .format-image .entry-summary
{
    padding-top: 1em;
}
.single .format-image .entry-content, .single .format-image .entry-summary
{
    padding-top: 0;
}
/*=Images
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
img
{
    margin: 10px 0;
}
#supersized img
{
    margin: 0;
}
a img
{
    border: none;
}
p img
{
}
/*
Resize images to fit the main content area.
- Applies only to images uploaded via WordPress by targeting size-* classes.
- Other images will be left alone. Use "size-auto" class to apply to other images.
*/
img.size-auto, img.size-full, img.size-large, img.size-medium, .attachment img, .widget-area img, .wp-caption
{
    max-width: 100%;
/*When images are too wide for containing element, force them to fit.*/
    height: auto;
/*Override height to match resized width for correct aspect ratio.*/
}
img.alignleft
{
    margin-right: 1em;
}
img.alignright
{
    margin-left: 1em;
}
.wp-caption
{
    text-align: center;
}
.wp-caption img
{
}
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text
{
    margin: 0.5em;
}
.gallery-caption
{
}
.wp-smiley
{
    margin: 0;
}
/*=Forms
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
button, #submit {
background: #222;
border: 1px solid #666;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
padding: 5px 10px;
width: auto;
color:#aaa;
}
#searchform label
{
    display: none;
}
#searchform {
    padding:10px;
}
#searchform input#s
{
    width: 60%;
}
input[type=text], input#s
{
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
    width: 60%;
}
textarea
{
    width: 80%;
}
/*Class for labelling required form items*/
.required
{
    color: #CC0033;
}
/*=Comments
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#comments
{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
article.comment
{
    display: block;
}
#respond input[type=text]
{
    display: block;
    width: 60%;
}
#respond textarea
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 80%;
}
#respond .form-allowed-tags
{
    clear: both;
    width: 80%;
}
#respond .form-allowed-tags code
{
    display: block;
}
/*=Widgets
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.widget
{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.widget ul
{
    margin: 5px 10px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.widget ul li
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #222;
}
.widget ul li a, .widget ul li a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
}
.widget-area .widget_search
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.widget-area .widget_search input
{
    float: left;
}
/*=Footer
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#colophon
{
    padding: 10px;
    background: #000000;
}
/*Gallery
---------------------------------------------------------------*/
#content .gallery .gallery-item img
{
    border:0;
    width: 350px;
    height: 175px;
    padding: 0;
}
#content .gallery .gallery-item {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    text-align:left;
}
#main #content .gallery-caption
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#main .image-attachment
{
    width: 100%;
}
.entry-attachment img
{
    width:650px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.attachment-thumbnail { 
    width:350px; 
    height:175px; 
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: We can't help you if we can't see some code or a URL! You can use an URL shortener.

Comment: Are you using external fonts? Is this a "responsive" site? Is there any javascript acting on the fonts? (slabtext.js fittext.js)? My guess is there is some javascript acting on the fonts and it doesn't load properly.

Comment: @Leeish No it is not a responsive site. There might be some javascript going on with fonts. I'll find out and let you know.

Comment: @NabilKadimi. Ok:, here it is: http://shoutkey.com/brackish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. I was using rem based font sizes. However for some strange reason I was getting gigantic font size on size occations, some other times it was working as expected.

Reverting to tradition px sizes, did do the trick. I know it is not the best solution, but I got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are zoomed in. Check this by pressing Ctrl+0.